# Is there a way to place a view on top of a tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

Right now I'm attempting to "extend the navigation bar" by placing a view under the navigation bar with the same color.

The only problem is that I'm using a tableview underneath. And tableviews extend all the way to the top.

I was wondering if there was a way to move the tableview down, so that I could place a view between the navigationbar and the start of the tableview.

Thanks!

Comment: Is a table view header (view) not an option?

Comment: I've tried that, but the problem is the header scrolls WITH the cells. I essentially want to simulate a larger navigation bar.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. It would help us to better understand your problem if you could provide more detail. Are you building views in code or using a storyboard? What have you attempted in an effort to solve your problem - i.e. what has not worked? Where in the view hierarchy have you tried to place the view? Are you familiar with or have you attempted to use stack views?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew. I'm doing programmatic UI. I have attempted to add a header view, which has NOT worked because the header scrolls with the other cells. I want to basically have a "bigger" navigation bar to display some info! So essentially I need the view to "stick" on the top. I have tried placing the subview on the viewcontroller's view so the same hierachy as the tableview. Unfortunately the tableview takes up the entire view, so the label I add is always off screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to constraint the top of the table to the bottom of the view or set top inset to the table